# Using cloud to store VS projects source and settings files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, google-drive-api, cloud

I would like to store Visual studio projects sources and settings on Google drive to be accessed by multiple devices(not at the same time).
But one of my problem is my uploud bandwidth (Under 1Mbit/sec) and some projects, even smaller ones, sometimes are 500MB or more in size. And as you probably guess, every time I save my work it takes ages to uploud to the cloud.
I don't know why the projects folders are so big in size, the project source files are just a few MBs.
What I want is just a way of uploud only the projects sources and settings automatically, as soon as they are created, and leave those have stuff (if possible) on the local machine. In order to sync faster on the cloud

Comment: Use one of the web-based source code control systems (eg github).  You are uploading all the binary files, debug databases etc.; these should not be upload but only rebuilt if their source changes.

Comment: You really don't want to compile files over a network or especially over the internet.  Compilation places a large bandwidth over the I/O channel.  Local drives are a better choice.  Use the cloud as a *source code repository* and use a SCM tool.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for the opinion, is there any free option with private storage? Without publishing the code for everyone?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I like that ideia, is there any plugin or something for VS that can help uploading the files?

Comment: I have no idea, search the internet for "git visual studio" or "github visual studio".  I'm using PTC with Visual Studio; I create local sandboxes with PTC, then develop using Visual Studio.  I don't fetch from the source code repository using Visual Studio.

Comment: Modern Visual Studio versions (2017 at least) don't need a plugin for GitHub. However, GitHub is either free or private, unless you're a student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using "visual studio team services" (included in visual studio), once it was free and feature unlimited private git repos, to make my git available online. Now I can edit across devices.